# Ubuntu installation on external drive

Tags: partitioning

while installing ubuntu, i get to a page where it gives us an option to install it alongside windows.after selecting this option, an orange bar with a slider comes up to allocate space for ubuntu and my files on my external hard drive. will this allocating erase data from  my external drive?

Comment: Be careful, "alongside" might be on your internal disk.  Use the "something else" option instead and choose where you want to put things.

Answer (score 0):

No, the installer does not delete any data unless you tell it specifically to do so by removing an existing partition. Depending on the health of your drive, though, it is possible that some data may be lost during a partition resize or move. Even though the installer does nothing more than reallocate the existing free space, it is *always* a good idea to make a back-up before installing. Generally, it's just always a good idea to make a back-up before doing anything.